# Laplace Equation in Three Dimensions - Ball of Radius B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, method-of-images

Consider the region $ V = {x ∈ R^3  |  | x ≥ b }$ outside a ball of radius $b$ and a charge distribution $ρ$ in $V$ given by a point charge $q$ located at $y ∈ V$. Using the method of mirror charge, solve the Laplace equation $∆\phi = −4πρ$ in $V$, subject to the boundary condition $φ_{|x|=b} = 0$. Generalise to the case where $ρ$ corresponds to a number of point charges $q1, . . . , qn$ located at $y1, . . . yn ∈ V$.

I started by using the div theorem and flux to find the potential inside and outside but I think I've done it all wrong and I would appreciate some help on how to start this question correctly as it is confusing me quite a bit.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations like 'div theorem' that many here won't understand. Also, I think you meant charge **density**, for $\rho$?

Comment: *I started by using the div theorem and flux to find the potential inside and outside but I think I've done it all wrong [...]* You should really include your work in your question.